# past simple or present perfect with since

Tags: grammar

I have  just finished reading a good book and say:

"It has been a long time since I have read a good book ." 
if I want to emphasize the gap in time between the last time I read a good book and now ;

or is it better to write " since I read a good book ". But I think in this case it is not the gap in time between now and the last time I read a good book I emphasize

Comment: Considering that you've already finished reading the book at that point, I think I would say this instead: "It had been a long time since I (had) read a book this good." Another alternative, "It was a long time since I (had) read a book this good," also sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, "It has been a very long time since I have read a good book".
Here, the emphasis is on the time.

This reminds me of the sentence "I didn't say you stole my money". Here, emphasis can be stressed on every word in the statement to provide a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound right. I would say use very to emphasize time:

"It has been a very long time since I read a good book."

Answer (score 0):

Be confident. You emphasize the time when you say "it's been a long time since I have read a good book or it's been  a long time since I read a good book". You can also say "it has been ages since i have read a good book".

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with the crowd, with this modification:

It's been a long time since I read a book that good.

It's = it has

Answer (score -3):

The general template for this type of sentences is ''It`s a long time/it has been a long time since somebody did something/something happened''. The only option for the 'since-clause' is the past simple tense...

Comment: The *only* option? *It has been a long time since anyone has called me 'Junior'*. *It had been a long time since anyone had called her lovely.* *It had been a long time since anyone was driving without wearing a seat belt.* *It had been a long time since anyone would dare contradict the general*.

Comment: Yes. "It has been a long time since anyone has called me 'Junior'" is grammatically wrong for that same reason.The rest of your sentences don`t fit the pattern of the original sentence and refer to the past perfect tense.It`s  a bit different story.

Comment: You will find plenty of examples of *It has been a long time since anyone has* in Google Books and elsewhere. Assuredly, they are not all wrong.